# Implementing a kill switch to a REST resource - either get the response or an error

Tags: design, rest, error-handling

We have one feature in our REST API which could have a reason to be shutdown temporarily, or permanently. Let's say the resource is:

`www.myapp.com/api/v1/needs_shutdown`

Right now, `/needs_shutdown` is a GET request that returns data. We want to make returning data happen only if the service is marked as `active` in our configuration.

So, how do we implement the *response*? The response could be one of two things:

Service is `active`, meaning they get data that fits a `NeedsShutdown` object:

```
{
    here: "is",
    some: "data",
}
```

or service is `inactive`, and the response data would fit some kind of `Error` object:

```
{
    error: "Service is unavailable",
    code: 123456789,
    other: "important data"
}
```

So the client would expect either a `NeedsShutdown` object, or an `Error` object. Specifically we're using Android (Java) with the Retrofit library, if that makes a difference in the design possibilities.

How should we design this REST endpoint to have this kind of optional behavior?

Comment: What about inheritance? `NeedShutdown` and `Error` extends/implements `ApiResponse`. Finally force endpoints to return ApiResponse instead of an specific response type. I know some more approachs but all of them tied to Spring Framework. Just a question. Does these two responses cause Http status 200? For the error you are encosing there's an Http status.

Comment: The Http status I was refering to is 503.

Comment: 503 is the right one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503 and check retry after which may prevent clients from keeping trying. When your service stops finally and never comes back you send 404.